# ruby** reverse array without using reverse method

Tags: ruby

This is my array and custom method to reverse an array output without using the reverse method. not sure where it broke, tried running it in console, no dice.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def reversal(array)
  do |item1, item2| item2 <=> item1
end

p reversal(numbers)
```

Comment: Before one can consider it "broken", it has to have been in a working state, first.  Do you understand what `<=>` does?

Comment: I wasn't sure, doesn't it reverse the order of 2 objects?

Comment: [**No.**](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) Very much ***no***.

Comment: But isn't there a way to utilize a combined comparison operator within a user created method that can be used to reverse an array when invoked?

Comment: Are you trying to make the array reverse-_sorted_, or just reversed? Like, if you had the array `[1,3,2]`, is the correct output `[3,2,1]` or `[2,3,1]`?

Comment: Also, there's a pretty significant syntactical error going on here as well... `do` and the `do |stuff|` construct are part of a method _call_, not a method _definition_. Of course, you can call a method from within the body of another method, but you're not doing that. Also, every `do` needs a corresponding `end` regardless.

Comment: If I had an array with the numbers [1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5, 6], I wanted the reverse of that array print out [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]. 

I think that's a huge part of my confusion theredifference between a method call vs a method definition. the clears answer I've gotten was:

def methodname(arguments)
     -->codeblock
end

I take it that's  method definition? and a method invocation would be something else? Really unsure what....

thanks for your help!

Comment: @WestCoastCharlie Your example doesn't clarify the question, because `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` is _already in order_, so putting it _backwards from what it is now_ and _backwards from 'in order'_ is the same thing. What if you had a list that was `[1,2,4,5,6,3]`? Would you want the result to be `[6,5,4,3,2,1]` or `[3,6,5,4,2,1]`?

Comment: Why don't you use the reverse method anyway? I sounds like your trying to reinvent the wheel. Could this be part of a learning exercise by any chance?

Comment: In any case, a method definition is something that begins with `def` and ends with `end`, whereas a method invocation is where you call the method. From `def reversal(array)` to `end` is a method definition (though not a valid one). The last line is a method call (actually two method calls, one call to `reversal` and one call to `p`). Method calls _can_ include a 'block' (though many don't), which is a bunch of code between `do` and `end` or between `{` and `}`. Like in @roychri's answer below, he passes a block to the method `loop`

Comment: @philomory I'd want the solution to an already sorted array where the numbers are already sorted. All I wanted is to reverse that sorted order.

Comment: @roychri This is just one of the exercises I'm doing to learn how about ruby methods.... believe me I would have used reverse method but exercise told us we were supposed to see if we can create our own. Seeing as how I'm still confused defining and calling method I understand now why I'd have trouble with this exercise.

Comment: @WestCoastCharlie So, are you saying that you want your method to take an pre-sorted array and reverse it, and it doesn't matter what it does when the input array isn't pre-sorted? It can crash, or return the wrong answer, doesn't matter?

Comment: @WestCoastCharlie If you go in a chat room I created, we can discuss it even further. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125765/helping-west-coast-charlie

Comment: @philmory, I had to read the question a couple times to comprehend it and to realize the answer I give prior may have unforseen and possibly unpleasent consequences..... what I had always wanted is if I was given a sorted array it would simply reverse the order. now for an unsorted array of numbers I'd like to reverse its order as well the example you've given me [1,2,4,5,6,3] I'd like [3,6,5,4,2,1] back. I hope that clarifies

Comment: I got 3 rep points I'm silenced in the room I need 20 points

Comment: Thank you both for trying so hard setting up the chat room and trying to get me to understand method definition and method calling, if nothing else really warmed by the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to handle this. This is not very efficient but works.

```
def reversal(array)
    reversed = []
    loop do
        reversed << array.pop
        break if array.empty?
    end
    reversed
end
```

Here is another implementation that does the same thing:

```
def reversal(array)
    array.each_with_index.map do |value, index|
        array[array.count-index-1]
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks roychri. I'm still confused as how a combined comparison operator fits into all this if it doesn't reverse the order of objects.

Comment: The comparaison operator is used to sort. What you want to do is reverse the array so that if the array contains [4,2,8] it becomes [8,2,4]. You cannot sort it in that case. just you take the last one and make it first, and so on.

Comment: @WestCoastCharlie The combined comparison operator _doesn't_ fit into all of this, it's completely unrelated. That operator is just a combination of `<`, `==`, and `>` into one operator; so, instead of returning `true` or `false` it returns `-1` (for 'a is less than b`), `0` (for 'a is equal to b') or `+1` (for 'a is greater than b').

Comment: While both methods return the reverse array, the first empties `array`: `array = [1,2,3]; reversal(array) #=> [3,2,1]; array = []`. I think you should either leave `arr` unchanged or replace it with the `arr` reversed (depending on West Coast Charlie's needs), but certainly not replace it with an empty array.

Answer (score 3):

So many ways... Here are three (#1 being my preference).

```
numbers6 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
numbers5 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

For all methods `my_rev` below,

```
my_rev(numbers6)
  #=> [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
my_rev(numbers5)
  #=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

**#1**

```
def my_rev(numbers)
  numbers.reverse_each.to_a
end
```

**#2**

```
def my_rev(numbers)
  numbers.each_index.map { |i| numbers[-1-i] }
end
```

**#3**

```
def my_rev(numbers)
  (numbers.size/2).times.with_object(numbers.dup) do |i,a| 
    a[i], a[-1-i] = a[-1-i] , a[i]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

there are so many ways to do this

## 1 Conventional way

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
i=1
while i <= a.length/2 do
  temp = a[i-1]
  a[i-1] =  a[a.length-i]
  a[a.length-i] = temp
  i+=1
end
```

## 2 Using pop

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
i=0
b=[]
t=a.length
while i< t do
  b << a.pop
  i+=1
end
```

## 3 Using pop and loop

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
b=[]
loop do
  b << a.pop
  break if a.empty?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = []
a.length.times { |i| b << a[(i+1)*-1] }
b
=> [5,4,3,2,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can implement the array reversal functionality without using built-in ruby methods.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
counter = 0
size = (arr.size/2.0).round(0)

while counter <= size - 1
    first_el = arr[counter]
    arr[counter] = arr[-(counter+1)]
    arr[-(counter+1)] = first_el
    counter += 1
end
p arr
```

This sample code will shift the array elements without creating a new array.